# Axios POST request to AIQuiz API returns partial data

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios, openai-api

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = "https://aiquiz-api.vercel.app/quiz";

function validateParams(params) {
  // ... (validation code)
}

async function makeDelayedRequest(params) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, {
      theme: params.theme,
      lang: params.lang,
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
}

async function getQuestions(params = {
  theme: "default theme",
  lang: "en", 
  count: 10
}) {
  validateParams(params);

  const responses = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < params.count; i++) {
    const response = await makeDelayedRequest(params);
    responses.push(response);
    
  }

  return responses;
}

// Calling the getQuestions function
getQuestions({
  theme: "movies",
  lang: "english",
  count: 10 
}).then(responses => {
  console.log(responses); 
});

export default getQuestions;
```

I am using the `getQuestions` function in my application to fetch 10 questions from the AIQuiz API. The API is built using the openai API and can be found at this GitHub repository: https://github.com/ulemisty/aiquiz-api

However, the problem I am facing is that when I call the `getQuestions` function with the parameters `{ theme: "movies", lang: "english", count: 10 }`, it only returns 2-3 questions instead of the expected 10.

I suspect that this might be due to rate limits imposed by the OpenAI API on the AIQuiz API. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can modify my code to reliably fetch all 10 questions from the AIQuiz API? Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you get 2-3 questions, what happened to the other 7-8 http requests?  Can you check the responses?  Do you get `null`s in your responses array?  If so what errors (from `console.error`) do you get?

Comment: I tried it in codesandbox, [Object, Object, Object, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""] this is the response i got,  first three are valid object containing info. I tried with postman as well through postman Im getting only one response at a time. May be some issue with OpenAPI.

Comment: @Prabhu I think there is some limitation on the number of requests to the OpenAI API but I tried to use ```setTimeout``` I was able to get more responses but not all and the time increased SO MUCH